# javaScript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sign' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create simple maths program for my young daughter - Basically, I just use + and - and do simple sums like 2+2=4 in the form of:

q1 (+ or -) q2 = ans

I dont want the answer to be a negative number at this stage so I wrote an if statement to try to say that if q1 is less than q2 only use the '+' operator in the equation. However, this is throwing the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sign' of undefined.

When I click the button I expect to see random numbers displayed, a random operator ( except when the if condition is met) and the correct answer calculated. It works sometimes and other times it throws an error and calculates the incorrect answer...

HTML

```
<div id = "ques1"></div>
<div id = "oper"></div>
<div id = "ques2"></div>
<div id = "equals">=</div>
<div id = "ans"></div><br>
<button onclick="miniMaths()">click</button>
```

JS

```
function miniMaths() {
  var operators = [
    {
      sign: "+",
      method: function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
      }
    },
    {
      sign: "-",
      method: function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
      }
    }
  ];
  var q1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  var q2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);

  if (q1 > q2) {
    var selectedOperator = Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length);
  } else {
    var selectedOperator = operators[0];
  }
  var calc1 = operators[selectedOperator].sign;
  var answer = operators[selectedOperator].method(q1, q2);
  document.getElementById("ques1").innerHTML = q1;
  document.getElementById("ques2").innerHTML = q2;
  document.getElementById("oper").innerHTML = calc1;
  document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

Comment: In your `if...else` you're setting `selectedOperator` to an integer (index) in the first case and to an Object (element at index) in the second case. It should be `if (q1 > q2) { ... } else { var selectedOperator = 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (q1 > q2) {
    var selectedOperator = Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length);
  } else {
    var selectedOperator = operators[0]; <----
  }
```

In this case, you have equalized the selectedOperator to the operators[0], which is

```
    {
      sign: "+",
      method: function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
      }
    }
```

After you have tried to get `operators[selectedOperator]` which is `undefined`

Your JS file should look like

```
function miniMaths() {
    var operators = [
        {
            sign: '+',
            method: function (a, b) {
                return a + b;
            },
        },
        {
            sign: '-',
            method: function (a, b) {
                return a - b;
            },
        },
    ];

    var q1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    var q2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

    if (q1 > q2) {
        var selectedOperator =
            operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)];
    } else {
        var selectedOperator = operators[0];
    }
    var calc1 = selectedOperator.sign;
    var answer = selectedOperator.method(q1, q2);
    document.getElementById('ques1').innerHTML = q1;
    document.getElementById('ques2').innerHTML = q2;
    document.getElementById('oper').innerHTML = calc1;
    document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = answer;
}
```

[EDIT]: Added Code snippet example

```js
function miniMaths() {
  var operators = [
      {
          sign: '+',
          method: function (a, b) {
              return a + b;
          },
      },
      {
          sign: '-',
          method: function (a, b) {
              return a - b;
          },
      },
  ];

  var q1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  var q2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

  if (q1 > q2) {
      var selectedOperator =
          operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)];
  } else {
      var selectedOperator = operators[0];
  }
  var calc1 = selectedOperator.sign;
  var answer = selectedOperator.method(q1, q2);
  console.log('calc1:', calc1);
  console.log('answer:', answer);
}

miniMaths()
```

Comment: i copied and paste you JS and it still throws the same error at me!

Comment: Looks like you are doing something wrong. Let me add code snippet

Comment: Please check the snippet @the_end

Comment: so i was testing this in Codepen.io and continually got the error. I opened a new browser to see what the pen would look like if i posted it here for your help and it doesnt bthrow any errors...Perhaps I need to find a better way to test JS in browser. THank you for solving this

Comment: You are welcome. Please be so kind to vote for the correct answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you have assigned an object to `selectedOperator`  in the else condition. Instead, you can simply assign the value of index position to it. Please find below code.

```
function miniMaths() {
  var operators = [
    {
      sign: "+",
      method: function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
      }
    },
    {
      sign: "-",
      method: function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
      }
    }
  ];
  var q1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  var q2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);

  if (q1 > q2) {
    var selectedOperator = Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length);
  } else {
    var selectedOperator = 0;   //This line
  }
  var calc1 = operators[selectedOperator].sign;
  var answer = operators[selectedOperator].method(q1, q2);
  document.getElementById("ques1").innerHTML = q1;
  document.getElementById("ques2").innerHTML = q2;
  document.getElementById("oper").innerHTML = calc1;
  document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

Comment: thank you this also worked in a new browser with codepen but not in original -i only up ticked previous solution as it appeared first, thank you

Comment: @the_end No problem. Maybe you need to hard reset the browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
var selectedOperator = operators[0];
```

the variable **selectedOperator** is going to be the index of your **operators** array and it must be an integer but you assigned your whole first object into that.

the q1 and q2 have random value, sometimes q1 is less than q2 and this will trigger that error.